# Unable to segue from View Controller to Storyboard Reference?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, uikit, segue

I would like to segue from storyboard A to storyboard B. I have created a storyboard reference to one of the views in storyboard B in storyboard A, but I am unable to create a segue from a view in storyboard A to my storyboard reference. Dragging the segue over on top of the reference does not lead to any sort of responsiveness. I am able, however, to segue from the reference to a view (which is not at all what I need).

The storyboard reference seems correctly linked to the view in storyboard B, so I am not sure what could be going wrong. And I have linked to storyboard references in my project before, and I don't see how the case right now is any different. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it sounds like you are doing something fundamentally wrong ... creating a two seperate storyboards (not view controllers in the same storyboard) each with one storyboard. You have to add a storyboard reference outlet into storyboard A, ctrl + Drag from view controller A to the storyboard reference. Add your identifier. In the storyboard reference you just linked to... make sure it is pointing to Storyboard B and references the viewController in storyboard B (assuming you dont want to go to the root) .. This "unexpected behaviour" shouldn't be happening

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you have to indeed drag the segue from the Storyboard Reference to the view, and this segues from the view to the referenced view. Utter non-intuitive madness, but it works.